# Basic webview app problems

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make a basic webview application, but it's giving 4 errors.

> Error:(35, 9) error: method does not override or implement a method
>   from a supertype
>
> Error:(46, 32) error: non-static method canGoBack() cannot be
>   referenced from a static context
>
> Error:(47, 32) error: non-static method goBack() cannot be referenced
>   from a static context
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (WebView.canGoBack()) {
                        WebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my new code now with your help which shows no errors, but still doesn't work(Failed to complete gradle execution, when I try to run it in the emulator):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private WebView mainWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

        WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
        mainWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
    }

    private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        public boolean shouldOvrrideLoading (WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
                        mainWebView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: use `mainWebView` for calling `canGoBack` and `goBack` method

Comment: Instance methods need to be called from an instance. As it's said in comment above " use *mainWebView.canGoBack()* and *mainWebView.goBack()* "

Answer (score 1):

The error actually explains what is wrong:

"**non-static** method goBack() **cannot be referenced from a static context**"

You need to replace the static `WebView.canGoBack()` with your instantiated webview `mainWebView.canGoBack()`

The same applies for `WebView.goBack()`

Comment: I also had to delete the second @Override and add a return statement at the 3rd line from the end and it says "Problem parsing package" or "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: Please post a stack trace for the crash, there's not enough information to conclude the cause.

Answer (score -1):

**mainWebView** variable should be object of class **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
        private WebView mainWebView;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mainWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);

            WebSettings webSettings = mainWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            mainWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
            mainWebView.loadUrl("http://facebook.com/");
        }

        private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }

        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                        if (mainWebView.canGoBack()) {
                            mainWebView.goBack();
                        } else {
                            finish();
                        }
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't much useful. Mind to write some explanation?

Comment: This code gave no errors, except that I needed to add a return statement in the line 3rd to the last:
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
But, if I try to install the application it says "There was a problem parsing the package" and on my friend's phone it installs and then it says "Unfortunately, app has stopped"

Comment: Where do I find the log files?

Comment: See LogCat in your IDE